# Why is my graphics card running at half the advertised speed?

Tags: graphics-card

Specs:
HP Envy 750-137c

Intel i7 6700 3.4 GHz CPU

12 GB of DDR3 RAM

300 W factory PSU

GPU: EVGA GTX 1050 Ti SuperClocked

Base Clock 1354 MHZ

Overclock 1468 MHZ

System Info in the NVidia control panel shows the GPU clock at 1354. However, running Speccy, my clock speed on the card is only shown as 670 MHZ. What is going on here? This particular card doesn't require an additional power source, it draws directly from the motherboard through the PCIe slot (75 W).  Is my system low on power? I just don't understand why it appears to be running at half the advertised speed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any type of power saver mode? Run Speccy while a Heavy/Benchmarking software is in use.

Comment: While I hate bad-mouthing an app, I have encountered cases where Speccy displays totally wrong info. For example, in its Operating System tab, the list of hotfixes is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with speccy but I would assume it only shows the current clock speed not the maximum.

I would recommend you to investigate with [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/). It shows you the clock speed and various other specs of your card and is also able to monitor the actual values over time. One very handy thing is the "PerfCap Reason" sensor. There it shows the reason why the GPU isn't doing more. If you have a power shortage then it would say so.